Field theories where the potential solves a linear Schrodinger equation
Are there physical situations/applications where the potential solves a linear time-dependent Schrodinger equation, or where the gradient of a solution to the Schrodinger equation (after somehow removing the phase) can be interpreted as a force?
For context, I'm a mathematician working in mathematical plasma physics and I usually work with the Vlasov-Maxwell equations, which describe collisionless plasmas interacting via a self consistent electromagnetic force. A (mainly mathematical) phenomena I'd like to understand better is exhibited by the so-called “Vlasov-Schrödinger” equations, where the Lorentz force is replaced by a field whose scalar potential is a solution to a linear Schrödinger equation rather than the Maxwell equations. This is mainly a toy model, but I'm wondering whether there's any possible physical interpretation for it.

Are you asking whether one can derive the classical harmonic oscillator from the quantum harmonic oscillator? Yes. We can. Is that an interpretation? No. It's a special case for large quantum numbers and short term approximation.

Could you give a reference to the equation you are referring to? In physics, it is mostly the Vlasov-Schröndinger-Poisson model that comes to mind. Your toy model seems very different, but without more precisions it is hard to compare.
